# Haskell - Turning a list into a list of object with index

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I do have a list in Haskell with the coordinates of some points, like:

> [[5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0],[6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5],[5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1]]

Already made a "Point" datatype

```
data Point = Point {
    pointSelf :: Int,
    coordinates:: [Float]
} deriving (Show)
```

I would like to make that list [[Float]] to become a list of [Point], with the attribute "pointSelf" being his index, how should I make it?

I am kinda new at Haskell and functional programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) to enumerate over two lists concurrently, and apply a function on the two items of the list. You thus can construct the `Point`s with:

```
zipWith Point [0 ..] myCoords
```

with `myCoords` the list of coordinates, so for the sample data, `myCoords` is `[[5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0],[6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5],[5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1]]`.